# What is the best way to integrate Vue JS on a back-end rendered App?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, vue.js

I have created a project which all pages and data are back-end rendered. Now my client wanted to integrate a SPA feature using vue js but only for a specific page not all pages, for example if I have home , contact, about us and then blog , its on the blog where I am going to apply a SPA using vue js . Btw I am using keystone js as backend framework.

Now the question is Do i need to scaffold a vue js project which would be blog and then integrate it on my existing ? is that ideal ? or I am just going to inline vue js to a specific page ? could that be possible ?

Do i need to scaffold a new vue js app and then integrate it ? how would i start the vue js app ? through navigation ? cause the SPA of my  app is only on a specific page , so for example if I navigate to blog which is the spa it will start the vue js spa app ? is that right ? or i am just going to inline the vue js app to a page ?

What is the best way of doing this ? Any idea?

## Sample of my backend rendered pages

```
exports = module.exports = function (req, res) {

    var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
    var locals = res.locals;

    // Set locals
    locals.section = 'blog';
    locals.filters = {
        post: req.params.post,
    };
    locals.data = {
        posts: [],
    };

    // Load the current post
    view.on('init', function (next) {

        var q = keystone.list('Post').model.findOne({
            state: 'published',
            slug: locals.filters.post,
        }).populate('author categories');

        q.exec(function (err, result) {
            locals.data.post = result;
            next(err);
        });

    });

    // Load other posts
    view.on('init', function (next) {

        var q = keystone.list('Post').model.find().where('state', 'published').sort('-publishedDate').populate('author').limit('4');

        q.exec(function (err, results) {
            locals.data.posts = results;
            next(err);
        });

    });

    // Render the view
    view.render('post');
};
```